# Bash select from array by argument

Tags: arrays, bash, select, element, ifs

I have an array filled with elements like these;

```
vars=($bla=123 foo=456 bar=789)
```

Now, i can use these and split them with IFS '=' like this:

```
for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
    IFS='=' read -a split <<< ${vars}
    nr=${split[1]}
    title=${split[0]}
```

Which works perfectly.

However, i want to be able to select for instance item foo=456 by passing an argument to the script like 'foo'. 'foo' would be $2. Is this possible in bash?

I was thinking in this direction :

```
"${vars[@]$2}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use associative array (needs bash 4+):

```
#!/bin/bash
bla=xyz
declare -A vars=([$bla]=123 [foo]=456 [bar]=789)

set -- one foo
echo ${vars[$2]}
```

Comment: Awesome! As i am reading this from a csv, would it be possible to convert my existing array to an associative array? This way i can keep my csv a bit cleaner so to speak

Comment: @volc: Feel free to ask a new question.